# How to show that $\chi_{A_n} \to \chi_{A}$ iff $P(A_n \triangle A) \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Here is the problem:

> Let $A, A_1, A_2, \ldots$ be events in some probability space. Show that $\chi_{A_n} \to \chi_{A}$ iff $P(A_n \triangle A) \to 0$.

My attempt:

For the $"\implies"$ direction: If we take some $\omega \in A$ then $A \subset A_n$ for all $n \geq N$. So $A_n \triangle A = A_n \setminus A$ and $P(A_n \triangle A) = P(A_n)- P(A)$. But it's unclear how to show that the latter goes to zero.

For the $"\impliedby"$ direction: Recalled that $\chi_{A_n \triangle A} = \chi_{A_n} + \chi_{A} - 2\chi_{A_n \cap A}$ yet it doesn't seem to help.

And one more thing which might be relevant for the solution: this problem is from the section "convergence in probability".

Comment: Don't use `\bigtriangleup`, rather, use `\triangle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: "$\Leftarrow$" Take any $\epsilon>0$. Note that:
$$\{|\chi_{A_n}-\chi_A|<\epsilon  \} \supseteq \{|\chi_{A_n}-\chi_A|<\min (\epsilon,1)  \} = \Omega \setminus \left(A_n\bigtriangleup A\right).$$
For "$\Rightarrow$" take $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: Awesome hints, thank you!